# Will extend create an object of its super class.?

Tags: java

I am confused with this simple question. Can anyone help me with a valid answer.

```
 public class SuperClass{
   public SuperClass(){
     // may or may not have a constructor for superclass
   }
 }
 public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
      // anything here
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
       SubClass sub=new SubClass(); 
    }
 }
```

> Now my question is if i am creating an object of the `SubClass` does
>   it create an ***object*** of the `SuperClass`
>   If yes why..??

I know most of the people see this question as silly. But these are my questions.

**It calls the constructor of the SuperClass so how does it do if an object is not created.?**

**Does the extends increase the size of the class ?** ie SuperClass+SubClass.!!

Comment: Why not just consult the java7 tutorials on extends? The answer is literally in the first paragraph!

Comment: I just saw the same question on a LinkedIn forum... is this the latest hot job interview question or something?

Comment: @ajb i got confused with the question in linkedIn so i posted it here. In linked in no one is giving an answer with proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is if i am creating an object of the SubClass does it create an object of the SuperClass If yes why..??

No. it's not.

When you do

```
SubClass sub=new SubClass();
```

only `SubClass`  object created.And only constructor of **super** class calls. And that calling to super class constructor chained untill the reaches to  `java.lang.Object`  constructor.

**Side note:** A thumb of rule(don't know it is official or not, *with each **new** ,only one object creates*)

You refer :[15.9.4 Run-time Evaluation of Class Instance Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.9.4)

> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified class type and all its superclasses. As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

So you can come to a conclusion like   when `class SubClass extends SuperClass`, then  methods,variables are copied to class `SubClass` .

**Edit:**

> how can a constructor be called if an object is not created..??

Aah...your doubt making sense to me.

But `constructor` is very special method in java. You can decompile a class file ,you can see the constructors in the name of `<init>.` You cannot call **explicitly** except with keyword `new` or `super`.

Comment: so you are saying it will not go any beyond the constructor, but how can a constructor be called if an object is not created..??

Comment: Yes that helps, i am going to keep the post open for some more time, let some more informations flow in :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a simple yes/no answer because it depends on the exact definitions of the terms you're using.  When you say

```
SubClass sub = new SubClass();
```

this will create *one* object (not counting any other objects created by the constructor body or initialization of member fields).  The object has a *runtime class*, which will be `SubClass`.  If you say `sub.getClass() == SubClass.class`, this returns `true`.  If you say `sub.getClass() == SuperClass.class`, this returns `false`.  So in that sense, the answer is no, because the object's (runtime) class is `SubClass`, not `SuperClass`.

However, the new `SubClass` object is also considered to be an "instance" of `SuperClass`; if you say `sub instanceof SuperClass`, this expression is `true`.  You can also use `sub` anywhere a `SuperClass` is needed, e.g. if you have a variable `SuperClass s` you can assign `s = sub`, and if a method needs a `SuperClass` parameter, you can pass `sub` to it.  In OOP, inheritance (`extends` in Java) denotes an **is-a** relationship, and in that sense, a `SubClass` **is a** `SuperClass`, and therefore `sub` also **is a** `SuperClass`.  But note that its runtime class *never* changes.

```
SuperClass s = sub;
boolean b1 = (s.getClass() == SuperClass.class);  // false
boolean b2 = (s.getClass() == SubClass.class);    // true
```

Of course, to answer the exact question "does it create an object of the SuperClass", the answer could be yes if the constructor looks like

```
public SubClass () {
    this.myParent = new SuperClass();
}
```

Now the constructor creates an object of `SubClass` and a separate object of `SuperClass`.  But I'm sure that's not what you meant.  :)

**EDIT:** To address the questions you added later:

> It calls the constructor of the SuperClass so how does it do if an object is not created.?

The `SubClass` object contains the member fields declared for `SuperClass`, *plus* the member fields declared for the `SubClass`.  (Plus the member fields declared for `Object` and any other superclass in between.)  But it's still just one object containing all those fields.  The `SubClass` constructor calls a `SuperClass` constructor, which (probably) initializes the fields declared for `SuperClass`; then the `SubClass` constructor can initialize the fields declared for the `SubClass`.

> Does the extends increase the size of the class ? ie SuperClass+SubClass.!!

If new member fields are declared in the `SubClass`, then yes, a `SubClass` presumably uses more memory, since it has all the fields declared in the `SuperClass` plus all the fields declared in the `SubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing.
- You don't create SuperClass object because the only created object is a SubClass object.
- In another perspective, yes, you do create a SuperClass object because a SubClass object is a SuperClass object. In other words, "SuperClass obj = new SubClass();" is totally valid
- SuperClass's constructor is called

Answer (score 0):

No it does not create Superclass Object. Although as it inherits from the superclass , it does run its constructor and intialisation blocks(if any) , and also gets its state and behaviour.